# Pyqt5 progress bar not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to create a progress bar that shows the update progress in the pyqt5 trayicon application. The progress bar window is opening when I call it using the menu button function called "Test" but not opening when it is being called by the update function.

> I have added the code for the reference

**The progress bar code:**

```
class Thread(QThread):

_signal = pyqtSignal(int)
def __init__(self):
    super(Thread, self).__init__()

def __del__(self):
    self.wait()

def run(self):
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self._signal.emit(i)

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('QProgressBar')
        self.btn = QPushButton('Click me')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btnFunc)
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        self.resize(300, 100)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.pbar)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
      

    def btnFunc(self):
        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread._signal.connect(self.signal_accept)
        self.thread.start()
        self.btn.setEnabled(False)

    def signal_accept(self, msg):
        self.pbar.setValue(int(msg))
        if self.pbar.value() == 99:
            self.pbar.setValue(0)
            self.btn.setEnabled(True)
            self.close()
```

**Class TrayIcon Code:**

```
class SystemTrayIcon(QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon):


def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
    self.w = Example()
    print("this is progress bar object")
    print(self.w)

    QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parent)

    self.about_app = menu.addAction("About")
    self.about_app.triggered.connect(self.about)

    self.open_logs = menu.addAction("Logs")
    self.open_logs.triggered.connect(self.openlogs)

    self.open_app = menu.addAction("Open")
    self.open_app.triggered.connect(self.open)

    self.start_app = menu.addAction("Reconnect")
    self.start_app.triggered.connect(self.start)

    self.start_app = menu.addAction("Test")
    self.start_app.triggered.connect(self.progress_bar)


    self.connectivity_manager = ConnectivityManager()

    self.update_app = menu.addAction("Check for Update")
    self.update_app.triggered.connect(self.update)

    menu.addSeparator()

    self.exit_ = menu.addAction("Exit")
    #exit_.triggered.connect(lambda: sys.exit())
    self.exit_.triggered.connect(self.exit)

    self.setContextMenu(menu)
    
    def progress_bar(self):
        self.w.show() # when this function is called through the menu button the progress bar opens

    def update(self):
        updater(self.w,is_manual_update=True)
```

**The updater code which resides in the updater file:**

When this function is is called the progressBar doesn't show up!! Neither any exception or error is raised.

```
def updater(progressBar,is_update_manual=True):
try:
    progressBar.show()
    print("this is progress bar object")
    print(progressBar)
except Exception as e :
    print(e)
```

Comment: You're calling `updater`, but there's no function named like that. Please provide a valid [mre], and also ensure that you're properly [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362), as there are various indentation issues.

Comment: @musicamante sorry for the naming error updater i just missed it, other than that the indentation on my end is accurate, stackoverflow is not showing it correctly, it can be ignored otherwise.

Comment: No, your indentation is not correct and we cannot know if the problem is in your code or in the way you pasted it, and that's not something we can ignore, since indentation is fundamental in Python. Read the link above to learn how to *properly* format code, and ensure that it's correctly displayed in the post preview before submitting.